# XSLT - Copy partial attribute value using regular expression

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML is like as shown below:

```
<figure>
<subfigure>
<graphic id="c001_f001" position="center" fileref="images/9781626232396_c001_f001.jpg"/>
<legend><para><target/><emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Fig. 1.1</emph>    </emph><emph type="bold">Embryonic development</emph> (after Sadler)</para>
<para>Age in postovulatory days.</para>
</subfigure>
</figure>
```

Output Should be

```
<figure>
<subfigure id="c001">
<graphic id="c001_f001" position="center" fileref="images/9781626232396_c001_f001.jpg"/>
<legend><para><target/><emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Fig. 1.1</emph></emph><emph type="bold">Embryonic development</emph> (after Sadler)</para>
<para>Age in postovulatory days.</para>
</subfigure>
</figure>
```

XSLt:

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:value-of select="graphic/@id"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Every time the attribute "id" value is different. We need to copy and paste only first part of "id" value into subfigure id. Could you please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring-before` here.

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(graphic/@id, '_')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, better still, simplify the template with an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
  <subfigure id="{substring-before(graphic/@id, '_')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </subfigure>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, if you really wanted to use regular expressions, you could use `replace` instead

```
<subfigure id="{replace(graphic/@id, '(.+)(_.+)', '$1')}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Tim